# why if expression is always true in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm very new in shell script and I wrote this code to copy an input file from directory new1 to directory new2 if the file doesn't exist in second directory.

the problem is that the first if expression is always true and the code always print "file copied successfully" even if the file exists in second directory.

here is my code:

```
while true; do
            echo "enter a file name from directory new1 to copy it to directory new2 "
            echo "or enter ctrl+c to exit: "
            read input
            i=0
            cd ~/new2 
            if [ -f ~/new1/$input ]; then
                    i=1                    
            fi
            if [ $i -eq 0 ];then                   
                    cp ~/new1/$input ~/new2/
                    echo "####" $input "copied successfully ####"
            else
                    echo "#### this file exist ####"
            fi
done
```

I will be appreciated if any one tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: Shouldn't the if be `if [ -f ~/new2/$input ]; then` instead of `new1`?

Comment: Why are you using `i` at all, instead of just combining the two `if` statements using the `-f` test alone?

Comment: A silly warning, clean new2 directory while debugging or use different file names each time :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing the wrong file.  In addition, you probably want to refactor your logic.  There is no need to keep a separate variable to remember what you just did.

```
while true; do
    echo "enter a file name from directory new1 to copy it to directory new2 "
    echo "or enter ctrl+c to exit: "
    read input
    #i=0         # no use
    #cd ~/new2   # definitely no use
    if [ -f ~/new2/"$input" ]; then  # fix s/new1/new2/
        # diagnostics to stderr; prefix messages with script's name
        echo "$0: file ~/new2/$input already exists" >&2
    else
        cp ~/new1/"$input" ~/new2/
        echo "$0: ~/new1/$input copied to ~/new2 successfully" >&2
    fi
done
```

Take care to make your diagnostic messages specific enough to be useful. Too many beginner scripts tell you "file not found" 23 times but you don't know which of the 50 files you tried to access were not found. Similarly, including the name of the script or tool which produces a diagnostic in the diagnostic message helps identify the culprit and facilitate debugging as you start to build scripts which call scripts which call scripts ...

As you learn to use the command line, you will find that scripts which require interactive input are a dog to use because they don't offer command history, tab completion of file names, and other niceties which are trivially available to any tool which accepts a command-line file argument.

[`cp -u`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) already does what this script attempts to implement, so the script isn't particularly useful per se.

Note also that `~` is a Bash-only feature which does not work with `sh`.  Your script otherwise seems to be compatible with POSIX `sh` and could actually benefit from some Bash extensions such as `[[` if you are going to use Bash features anyway.

Comment: @z.k: Also note how tripleee always put double quotes around the variable expansions, like `"$input"`, which is always advisable, and which beginners often forget. Especially, for files with spaces in their name, not quoting them leads to errors.

Comment: More generally, you might want to try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human help (but of course it couldn't help with this particular bug).

Comment: thank you very very much for your complete answer. can't say how much it helped me!

Comment: I'd make at least one more change: only print the "copied ... successfully" if the `cp` command actually succeeded. Either with an `if` (or `elif`), or by joining it to `cp` with `&&`. I might also add a test to make sure `~/new1/"$input"` exists before trying to copy it; that way the user gets an error from this script rather than a from `cp` ("cp? I'm not using cp, I'm using this copy script z.k. gave me.").

Comment: Actually I'd simply use `cp -v` and of course `cp -u` but yeah.